# how to add ng-include callback to multiple ng-include directives in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have my HTML like this

```
  <form ng-controller="testCtrl1">
    <div ng-include="'test/views/navigationbar.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'test/views/processnav.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'test/views/leftprocesstabs.html'"></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I want to write generalized method to check all my ng-include file are loaded.

After loading all file i need to make a server call.

Is there any way to check this in angular js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the onload of each template and increment a counter.
if the form  contains only ng-include divs, use the beow code to get the count, or write a function to get the count of divs with ng-include.

HTML

```
<form ng-controller="testCtrl1" id="includes">
    <div ng-include="'test/views/navigationbar.html'"  onload="load()"></div>
    <div ng-include="'test/views/processnav.html'" onload="load()"></div>
    <div ng-include="'test/views/leftprocesstabs.html'" onload="load()"></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var templates = 0;
var length = $("#includes > div").length; 
$scope.load = function(){
    templates++;
    if(templates >= length){
        onLoadComplete()
    }

}
function onLoadComplete(){
    // all templates are loaded
}
```

Comment: this is not generalized bcus ng-include may not be 3 always

Comment: edited the code to take the div count , provided all the divs in the form are ng-include divs..

Comment: this requires jquery?

Comment: Yes that requires jquery but there are many other ways by whcih you can get the count.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-include` triggers a request that goes through the template cache. This is done async so No, angular cannot provide you with a trigger for when all templates done loading.

You can prefetch the templates to the cache and handle the event from there ...

For example,

```
// inject $q, $http, $templateCache to your controller 
...
var promises = [];
promises.push($http.get('test/views/navigationbar.html',{ cache : $templateCache }));
promises.push($http.get('test/views/processnav.html',{ cache : $templateCache }));
promises.push($http.get('test/views/leftprocesstabs.html',{ cache : $templateCache }));
$q.all(promises, function (data) { 
 console.log('All templates are loaded into the cache !');
});
...
```

Comment: thanks, i added this . not able to print  `console.log('All templates are loaded into the cache !');`