# How do i check all my html contents are loaded in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angularJS 1.2.1  and angular-ui-bootstrap

In my code i have list of `<ng-includes>` from angularjs and `<accordion>` from angular-ui

But when i load the content i want to make server call and get some values

i solved  using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779304/how-to-add-ng-include-callback-to-multiple-ng-include-directives-in-angular-js)

But now problem is with accordion, I am not able to get all scope variable

the scope outside accordion i am able to get but whatever contents inside accordion its not getting

I think this issue is with loading of accordion . 
Is there any way to check that accordion contents are loaded? 
any callback we can write to check accordion contents are loaded?

Comment: Can you include the controller code and the template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run function in angular controller on document ready?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646756/how-to-run-function-in-angular-controller-on-document-ready)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js - how to execute function on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/angular-js-how-to-execute-function-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

there are two approaches to do this.

1)

```
 // at the bottom of your controller
    var init = function () {
       // check if there is query in url
       // and fire search in case its value is not empty
    };
    // and fire it after definition
    init();
```

2)

```
  // register controller in html
    <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="init()"></div>

    // in controller
    $scope.init = function () {
        // check if there is query in url
        // and fire search in case its value is not empty
    };
```

you would find a good answer here [How to execute angular controller function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/angular-js-how-to-execute-function-on-page-load) by Dmitry Evseev